# Converting a mysql query to postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

This query works great in mysql but I'm trying to run it in postgresql and it's complaining about the `IGNORE` keyword, which is not a pg keyword. I'm not sure how to modify it to make it do the same under pg?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ct_tmp_u1101_t9;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ct_tmp_u1101_t9(id int primary key, shared int default 0) IGNORE (SELECT 1101 as id);
SELECT shared from ct_tmp_u1101_t9
UNION (SELECT cust_user2role.userid AS userid FROM cust_user2role
INNER JOIN cust_users ON cust_users.id = cust_user2role.userid
INNER JOIN cust_role ON cust_role.roleid = cust_user2role.roleid 
WHERE cust_role.parentrole like 'H1::H2::H3::H4::H5::%')
UNION (SELECT groupid FROM cust_groups where groupid in (3,4,2,1005));
```

Comment: What does the IGNORE do in MySQL?

Comment: The IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard any duplicate records without generating an error

Comment: How could that temp table contain rows if you dropped it the line before? You drop the table, re-create it and populate it with a single row (where shared gets the value 0 and the id = 1101). What is the intention behind this? I have the feeling that the temp table is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something absolutely obvious, I don't see the need for the temp table.

The following should return exactly the same result (unless there is some MySQL magic involved with temp tables)

```
SELECT 0 as shared
UNION 
SELECT cust_user2role.userid AS userid 
FROM cust_user2role
   INNER JOIN cust_users ON cust_users.id = cust_user2role.userid
   INNER JOIN cust_role ON cust_role.roleid = cust_user2role.roleid 
   WHERE cust_role.parentrole like 'H1::H2::H3::H4::H5::%'
UNION 
SELECT groupid 
FROM cust_groups 
WHERE groupid IN (3,4,2,1005);
```

(And I think the same should work with MySQL)